# How do I fix the sound of my game when I start a Skype call?

Tags: windows, skype

Whenever I am playing a game, and I call my friend on Skype, the sound on my game goes super low, to where I can barely hear it, and it remains the same all through the Skype call. However, though, when I end the call, my sound goes to normal again. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It's Skype, not the game.

Answer (score 3):

You want to go to

Control Panel -> Sound -> Communications tab

On there you will see the item that reduces the audio of other sources while using a communication application.. Skype counts as one of these as do other applications like Mumble and Team Speak. Set this to 'Do Nothing' and it should stop adjusting the volume when people speak to you over skype.